# How do I open a door that has a chainlock from the outside?

Tags: locks, door

I have a door that has a chain lock, like this:

[image: enter link description here]

Sometimes, my roomate locks me out with this thing. **How can I be able to open it from the outside?**

Comment: How do we know that you won't use this knowledge for evil?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Because I already know how to do it. They're very easy.

Comment: Call the police! It's illegal to lock out a legal tenant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[How to Open a Door Chain Lock or Bar Latch from the Outside](http://thesecretyumiverse.wonderhowto.com/how-to/open-door-chain-lock-bar-latch-from-outside-0134890/)

[image]

Image taken from the above site.

The one I believe in mostly is taking a piece of string and tying it to the chain, then threading it over to the outside of the door and pulling chain open. But I can vouch that all of these methods work.

For the rubber band method you can use a string that is tied, it doesn't have to be a rubber band. And if you are small you can stand on a stool and stick your hand in the door that is cracked and open the door that way. [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Break-Into-Your-House#For_a_Chained_Lock_sub) also had a method, but it includes pushing against the door.

Comment: Oh really? .....should I ask if it's legal? ;-)

Comment: Cool. Sounds like you're one of the "[experts](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/5/59)," then ;-)

Comment: Whatever you know can help the site....I've posted a few Q/A sets (and [one of those Qs](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-do-i-fill-a-hot-water-urn-when-it-doesnt-fit-in-the-sink) is tied for third place for most votes) ....if you're looking to fill your commitment (10 posts), I'd advise you to post some Q/A sets, based on+linked with your Instructables and WikiHow posts. That would be pretty cool :)

Answer (score 0):

For the type in this pic, with the door ajar, reach in with the key and unlock this chain that has it conveniently built-in for this very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a yarn, ribbon, thread, dental floss, thin rope, or any other string long enough that you can pull it from the top of the door when its end is attached to the chain lock. Imagine pulling up a bucket from a well.