# Filling a hot water urn from a kitchen sink

Tags: efficiency, sink

The answers given so far don't seem to work for my situation.

1. the hose would not be suitably hygienic, as it would not be sterile enough (I am working with elderly people and the hygiene is very important).
2. the urn becomes too heavy to lift up onto the counter top from  the floor (in the styrene cups example)
3. The same for the clean dustpan example.

Comment: I guess you are talking about [this question](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-do-i-fill-a-hot-water-urn-that-doesnt-fit-in-the-sink). Of course you can use these methods. If the only problem for you is the hygiene, then keep the thing you use clean as you keep the urn clean. You can use a clean hose dedicated only for this purpose, and after using it you will keep it in clean place. It wont be less hygienic than the urn. In the example with the cups you don't need to lift the urn, it can stay on the floor.